# How to retrieve values in a dynamically generated element using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Elements "SelectB" and "SelectC" were dynamically generated. 
When user changes something in "SelectB" I need to grab its value and "SelectC" value.

```
$('#SelectB').on('change',function() {
    var valB = $(this).val();
    var valC = $("#SelectC").val();
    console.log(valB); //Works good, because $('#SelectB').on ....
    console.log(valC); //Undefined    
});
```

So in this scenario how could I retrieve "SelectC" value?

This is the html (simplified), only example;

```
<select id="SelectB">
  <option value="0">Volvo</option>
  <option value="1">Saab</option>
  <option value="2">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="3">Audi</option>
</select>

<select id="SelectC">
  <option value="0">Volvo</option>
  <option value="1">Saab</option>
  <option value="2">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="3">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You may want to post sample html as well, and `console.log($("#SelectC"));`

Comment: You need to make sure that there's an element with the id `SelectC`.

Comment: If there's a parent element that was there on load, try `valC = $('#parent').find($('#SelectC')).val();`

Comment: it is not a parent. They are independent. I think the HTML I put can vige a better idea. They were not here on load. They were created later, dynamically

Comment: What's the element the select elements were added to?

Comment: If both are present it works. See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4yngno10/1/

Comment: let's say these 2 elements were created like this: "SelectB" value Volvo, and  "SelectC" value Audi. Let's say the user has change  "SelectC" to Saab and when the user changes  "SelectB"  again let's says to Mercedes, I need to grab the     "SelectB" chosen value and  "SelectB" chosen value

Comment: @R.Schifini, in your example they are working because they were not created dynamically. In my example they were.

Comment: As @marcan2020 stated before, since they are created dynamically you have no guarantee that element C has been created before the user chooses an option in B. If there is no element C then the result is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
 $(document).on('change', ['#SelectB','#SelectC'], function(){
   var valB = $("#SelectB").val();
   var valC = $("#SelectC").val();
   console.log(valB);
   console.log(valC);
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a generic algorithm to discover the pair of values based on data-attribute. The source bellow will show a alert window when fill both values.

```js
$('select').on('change',function() {
  var elem = $(this),
      id = elem.attr('id'),
      val1 = null,
      val2 = null,
      next = $(elem.data('next')),
      prev = null;
  
  if (next.length) {
    val1 = elem.val();
    val2 = next.val();
  } else {
    prev = $('[data-next="#' + id + '"]');
    val1 = prev.val();
    val2 = elem.val();
  }
  
  if (val1 && val2) {
    alert('val1: ' + val1 + ', val2: ' + val2);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<select id="#SelectB" data-next="#SelectC">
    <option value="">select</option>
    <option value="0">Volvo</option>
    <option value="1">Saab</option>
    <option value="2">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="3">Audi</option>
</select>

<select id="SelectC">
    <option value="">select</option>
    <option value="0">Volvo</option>
    <option value="1">Saab</option>
    <option value="2">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="3">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did some test and the only way to have `$("#SelectC").val() === undefined` is that the element is not created.

It's probably because you create `SelectB` before `SelectC`.

What it does is:

```
// SelectB.val() === undefined
// SelectC.val() === undefined
// SelectB created
// SelectB.val() === 0
// SelectC.val() === undefined
```

Try to create `SelectC` before or wait that they are both created before subscribing to the change.

It should work now:

```
// SelectC.val() === undefined
// SelectB.val() === undefined
// SelectC created
// SelectC.val() === 0
// SelectB.val() === undefined
// SelectB created
// SelectC.val() === 0
// SelectB.val() === 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working solution. Hope it helps!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select').on("change",function() {
    alert("SelectB value is: "+ $("#SelectB option:selected").val() + "\n"+ 
        "SelectC value is: " + $("#SelectC option:selected").val());
  });  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="SelectB">
  <option value="0">Volvo</option>
  <option value="1">Saab</option>
  <option value="2">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="3">Audi</option>
</select>

<select id="SelectC">
  <option value="0">Volvo</option>
  <option value="1">Saab</option>
  <option value="2">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="3">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a solution http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/32671/

```
<select id="SelectB">
  <option value="0">Volvo</option>
  <option value="1">Saab</option>
  <option value="2">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="3">Audi</option>
</select>
```

javascript

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var myhtml = '<select id="SelectC">'
    myhtml += '<option value="0">Volvo</option>'
    myhtml += '<option value="1">Saab</option>'
    myhtml += '<option value="2">Mercedes</option>'
     myhtml += '<option value="3">Audi</option>'
      myhtml += '</select>'
      $('body').append(myhtml);
});


$('#SelectB').on('change',function() {
    var valB = $(this).val();
    var valC = $("#SelectC").val();
    alert(valB); //Works good, because $('#SelectB').on ....
    alert(valC); //Undefined    
});
```